# How can i add all the elements which has same class in the variable using selenium in the python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

```py
content = driver.find_element_by_class_name('topics-sec-block')
container = content.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="col-sm-7 topics-sec-item-cont"]')
```

**the code is below:**

```py
for i in range(0, 40):
    title = []
    url = []
    heading=container[i].find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="col-sm-7 topics-sec-item-cont"]/a/h2').text
    link = container[i].find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="col-sm-7 topics-sec-item-cont"]/a')

    title.append(heading)
    url.append(link.get_attribute('href'))

    print(title)
    print(url)
```

it is giving me the 40 number of lines but all lines have same title and url as (some of them is given below):

```py
['Stuck in Mexico: Central American asylum seekers in limbo']
['https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2020/03/stuck-mexico-central-american-asylum-seekers-limbo-200305103910955.html']
['Stuck in Mexico: Central American asylum seekers in limbo']
['https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2020/03/stuck-mexico-central-american-asylum-seekers-limbo-200305103910955.html']
```